# How to open target ='_blank' Web Element and get it's screenshot?

Tags: java, selenium

The testpage I am working on is http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html in firefox.

In it I have to click on `Code Generator` `WebElement` and take a screenshot of the opened page with `Selenium Webdriver`, JAVA.
Whatever method I tried, Selenium is giving exception as

> Unable to locate element.

It has target as _blank.

Please find the code below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Quackit {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Code Generator "));
     // ensure that link always opens in the current window
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('target', arguments[1]);", e, "_self");


        e.click();
        for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
        }

        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source,new File ("./Screenshots/codegenerator.png"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help http://www.seleniumwiki.com/software-testing/how-to-solve-the-link-has-target-_blank-which-is-not-supported-in-selenium/

Comment: I didn't understand what was done in link suggested. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: hi..please provide the code what you tried and where is getting exception to help you

Comment: I shared my code above.

Comment: I even tried other code variations with Actions class, windowhandles, switch to also.but was not able to do it.

Comment: WurgspaB (hope I spelled it correct), I am not able to comment to your answer, but I got the following exception when I tried it    "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(.,'Code Generator')]}"

Comment: @Rathna I edited the code. It works for me. Please try again.

Comment: @Würgspaß Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
        driver.switchTo().frame("content");
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Code Generator')]"));
        e.click();
```

You have to switch to the frame first and should use `contains()` to locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Code Generator link is inside the frame/iframe. so if elements are inside the frame, first we need to switch into the frame then only we can find elements that frame.

Once work or actions inside frame is completed then need to switch on to default content.

```
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.switchTo().frame("content");

        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Code Generator"));
        e.click();

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

        //try for window handles here
```

Thank You,
Murali